# Bash list files with certain name range

Tags: bash, awk, ls

I have a directory that contains txt files with unique times that gets generated overnight. I am trying to list those files given the unique timestamps in the file.
Some example of file names are the following:

```
file_20210122_1130_1.txt 
file_20210122_1133_1.txt 
file_20210122_1221_1.txt 
file_20210122_1342_1.txt 
file_20210122_1721_1.txt 
file_20210122_1911_1.txt
file_20210122_2009_1.txt
file_20210122_2020_1.txt
file_20210122_2130_1.txt
...
```

I want the ability to list the files (using pattern contained in the filename itself) between 1900 and 2100 and it should list the following:

```
file_20210122_1911_1.txt
file_20210122_2009_1.txt
file_20210122_2020_1.txt
```

I am trying to use the below code snippet but it partially works and does NOT list all of the files.

```
cd /home/somedir/files;
ls *.txt | awk '/1900/,/2100/'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `printf "%s\n" *_19??_*.txt *_20??_*.txt`? See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls(1)`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your responses. I used answers from @the-fourth-bird and @dawg and tweaked it to make it work for me.

I used the following:

```
printf "%s\n" file_*.txt
```

to list all of the files and then the following:

```
awk -v a="$start" -v b="$stop" 'BEGIN {FS="_"}; {if($3 >= a && $3 <= b) print}'
```

to get files between 1900 (start) and 2100 (stop)

The final command is:

```
printf "%s\n" file_*.txt | awk -v a="$start" -v b="$stop" 'BEGIN {FS="_"}; {if($3 >= a && $3 <= b) print}';
```

It gives the output of (which I wanted):

```
file_20210122_1911_1.txt
file_20210122_2009_1.txt
file_20210122_2020_1.txt
```

Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 4):

If the format of the filenames are the same, you might use awk and set the field separator to `_` Then check if the 3rd field is between 1900 and 2100

```
ls -A1 *.txt | awk -v FS=_ '$3 >= 1900 && $3 <= 2100'
```

Output

```
file_20210122_1911_1.txt
file_20210122_2009_1.txt
file_20210122_2020_1.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't parse the output of `ls`.

```
$ shopt -s nullglob
$ printf '%s\n' *_{1900..2100}_*.txt
file_20210122_1911_1.txt
file_20210122_2009_1.txt
file_20210122_2020_1.txt
```

Comment: Would this still hold true if instead of 1900 and 2100, variables containing those values are used? For ex, printf '%s\n' *_{$start..$stop}_*.txt where start contains 1900 and stop contains 2100.

Comment: @AnandPatel No. You'd have to use `eval` for it, and that's just ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
$ ls -1
file_20210122_1130_1.txt
file_20210122_1133_1.txt
file_20210122_1221_1.txt
file_20210122_1342_1.txt
file_20210122_1721_1.txt
file_20210122_1911_1.txt
file_20210122_2009_1.txt
file_20210122_2020_1.txt
file_20210122_2130_1.txt
```

You can get [clean](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) filenames using `printf` and a [glob](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html) then use a [regex](https://regex101.com/r/AGVfxw/1) to filter the results:

```
printf "%s\n" file_*.txt | ggrep -oP 'file_\d{8}_(?:19\d\d|20\d\d|2100)_\d\.txt'
file_20210122_1911_1.txt
file_20210122_2009_1.txt
file_20210122_2020_1.txt
```